# maxima linsolve yields expression involving g20618

Tags: maxima

The code below yields the following output:

```
[V1 = 0.07219355466848408/g20618,V2 = 0.02780644533151591/g20618]
```

What is the meaning of the term g20618? And how can this be avoided?

```
display2d:false$
IS1:1e-12$
IS2:1.1e-12$
IS3:1.7e-12$
NVT1:0.05$
NVT2:0.051$
NVT3:0.056$
V0:0.1$
I1(V):=IS1*(exp(V/NVT1) - 1.0)$
I2(V):=IS2*(exp(V/NVT2) - 1.0)$
I3(V):=IS3*(exp(V/NVT3) - 1.0)$
e0:V1+V2-V0$
e1:I2(V2)+I3(V2)-I1(V1)$
t01:taylor(e1, [V1, V2], [0,0], 1)=0$
t02:taylor(e0, [V1, V2], [0,0], 1)=0$
eqns:[t01, t02]$
float(linsolve(eqns, [V1, V2]));
```

In case of I copy the two equations generated by taylor into a fresh maxima, I get the same solution WITHOUT the terms g20618. Potentially this got something to do with maxima not having a clear segregation of symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. What does `build_info();` report on your system? I don't get the same result; I am working with a current development version (post-5.46). I get `[V1 = 0.07219355466848408,V2 = 0.02780644533151592]` for the final result. Perhaps what you're seeing is a bug which has been fixed in a later version.

Comment: @RobertDodier

Maxima version: "5.43.2"
Maxima build date: "2020-02-21 05:22:38"
Host type: "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
Lisp implementation type: "GNU Common Lisp (GCL)"
Lisp implementation version: "GCL 2.6.12"
User dir: "/home/uname/.maxima"
Temp dir: "/tmp"
Object dir: "/home/uname/.maxima/binary/5_43_2/gcl/GCL_2_6_12"
Frontend: false

Comment: Frank, thanks for the info. Trying some different versions, it appears that the bug is present in versions up to and including 5.45, and not present in 5.46 (the most recent version). 5.43.2 is a couple of years old at this point, and a number of bugs have been fixed; maybe it makes sense to update to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

putting a trunc() around the call to taylor() fixes this problem.
This got something to do with taylor() not returning a truncated taylor series, but internally it stays infinite.